# ProtoBuf and TransLink

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, gtfs, protobuf-python

I've found this GTFS data that I want to use, but IDK how to set up protobuf (preferably in Python) to read the data. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

https://gtfsrt.api.translink.com.au/

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to download the protocol compiler from [here](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases). According to Protobuf guide on [GitHub](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf):

> In the downloads section of each release, you can find pre-built binaries in zip packages: protoc-$VERSION-$PLATFORM.zip

Second, compile `gtfs-realtime.proto` using following command:

`protoc -I=. --python_out=. ./gtfs-realtime.proto`

This will look for `gtfs-realtime.proto` in the current directory and generates a `.py` file which you can import in your project. For more information, check out [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/pythontutorial).
That's for the Protobuf part.

I don't have experience with GTFS, but I guess [this sample](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs-realtime/examples/python-sample) may help you.